# Shortcut to show a window on all virtual desktops in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, plasma, kwin, virtual-desktop

I am using KDE Plasma 5, and I want to define a shortcut to toggle showing the active window on all virtual desktops (a.k.a. pinning the window). I cannot find such a shortcut in the shortcuts list for KWin (System Settings -> Shortcuts -> KWin). Is there some other place I can define such a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possibly depends on the version of KDE-Plasma you are using.

On mine (5.25.5), System Settings -> Shortcuts -> KWin is indeed the right place for finding that shortcut which is labeled :

*Keep Window on All Desktops.*

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed it when I read through the list.